# Error al compilar en C [ error : expected '=', ',', ';' before `funcion`]

Tags: c, compilar

Al querer compilar el archivo `Raci.c` ejecutando `gcc Raci.c` se me muestra el siguiente error :

`Raci.c:32:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘WinMain’ 32 | int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {`

Llevo ya tiempo tratando de encontrar la solución y no consigo encontrarla.

Gracias de antemano y disculpas si es un fallo 'tonto' llevo poco tiempo estudiando C por mi cuenta.

Adjunto el contenido de `Raci.c` :

```
       │ File: Raci.c
───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │
   2   │ #include<stdio.h>     // Libreria estandar para valores entrada/salida
   3   │ #include<stdlib.h>    // Define 4 variables, macros y otras funciones generales
   4   │ #include<unistd.h>    // Proporciones acceso a la API de POSIX (Operating System Interface). Estander IEEE que permite compatibilidad entre diferente S.O.
   5   │
   6   │ #ifdef _WIN32
   7   │ #include<winsock2.h>  // Nos permite establecer conexiones con el servidor
   8   │ #include<windows.h>   // Definimos que trabajaremos con Windows y nos aporta compatibilidad con ciertas funciones
   9   │ #include<winuser.h>   // Permite diferentes funciones Windows Based
  10   │ #include<wininet.h>   // Permite conexiones inet (detallar)
  11   │ #include<windowsx.h>  // Mas compatibilidad Windows
  12   │ #endif
  13   │
  14   │ #include<string.h>    // Permite manipular arrays de characteres comodamente (strings(
  15   │ #include<sys/stat.h>  // Libreria C POSIX que contiene construcciones que facilitan obtención de información sobre atributos de archivos
  16   │ #include<sys/types.h> // Diferentes variables y estructuras...
  17   │
  18   │
  19   │ /*
  20   │ Función main/prinicpal donde estableceremos conexión con el servidor y especificaremos el resto de funciones.
  21   │
  22   │ APIENTRY => Alias de WINAPI (Explicamos al compilador como manejar el stack y argumentos al llamar la función)
  23   │
  24   │
  25   │     PARAMETERS :
  26   │
  27   │     HINSTANCE hInstance => Identificador de instancia / modulo. El S.O. utiliza este valor para identificar el EXE cuando es cargador en memoria.
  28   │     HINSTANCE hPrev     => Identificador de instancia previo
  29   │     LPSTR lpCmdLine     => Contiene la linea de comandos en un String Unicode (Nos da la shell utilizando un charset en casi todos los idiomas (UNICODE))
  30   │     int nCmdShow        => Indicador de tamaño de ventana CMD (pequeña, grande, invisible ...)
  31   │ */
  32   │ int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  33   │
  34   │     // Inicializaciones de consola
  35   │
  36   │     HWND stealth; // Identificador de ventana parte de Win32 API
  37   │     AllocateConsole(); // Inicializa nueva consola permitiendo entrada / salida y control de errores de esta misma.
  38   │     stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL); // Función para encontrar la ventana con ClassName "ConsoleWindowClass" sin especificar titulo. Busca la ventana / proceso
  39   │
  40   │     ShowWindow(stealth,0); // Inicializamos la consola sin mostrarla
  41   │
  42   │ }
```

Comment: creo que tienes mal puesto los parametros del WinMain(). ' HINSTANCE, hPrev' ?

Comment: @maxin739 Correcto ;) Aunque el error persiste

Comment: El mismo mensaje de error o cambió ?

Comment: Exactamente el mismo error

Comment: Tienes definido _WIN32 en algún sitio?

Answer (score 2):

Respondo a mi pregunta por si esto resuelve el mismo error a alguien.

Al querer compilar el archivo C `Raci.c` ejecutando un `gcc Raci.c` salta el error :

`Raci.c:32:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘WinMain’ 32 | int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {`

Esto es debido a que el compilador `gcc tiene como "target/destino" sistemas basados en Linux` y al querer compilar headers/encabezados con "target/destino" Windows based salta el error anterior.

**Extracto de la línea que indica target de gcc :**
`gcc -v : Target: x86_64-linux-gnu`

**Solución**
Utilizando el paquete `mingw32` podemos compilar y enlazar encabezados con destino Windows en nuestro sistema Linux.

- Instalación de mingw32 => `apt install mingw-64`
- Ejemplo para compilar/uso x64-bit =>  `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ [archivo.c]`
- Ejemplo para compilar/uso 32-bit => `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ [archivo.c]`